# Reference netstandard library from net20 app

Tags: c#, .net, project.json

I've got a .NET 2.0 framwork console app. How do I reference a netstandard1.0 library from this one? I'm doing project.json like so

```
"frameworks": {
  "net20": {}
}
```

And getting this error

`Project Reproducer is not compatible with net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0). Project Reproducer supports: netstandard1.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.0)
    One or more projects are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v2.0.`

Comment: You can't, as far as I'm aware. There are things that netstandard1.0 requires that aren't present in .NET 2.0. What's the context? Why do you need something as old as .NET 2.0?

Comment: Dot net standard only goes back as far as .NET Framework 4.5 Reference here : https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md

Comment: I see. Could you put this in an answer?

Comment: @vidstige I'm not sure if you were referring to my comment or Jon Skeet's

Comment: @JonSkeet it turned out I did not need .NET 2.0 at all, so solution was just to up to 4.5. All is fine and dandy, thanks a lot. If either of you two gentlemen could be kind enough to put in an answer, I can reward it, otherwise I'll self-answer in a few days.